# Get time between two times on night to morning

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table that stores schedules by initial hour to end hour, some structure like

```
| SCHEDULE_NAME | START_HOUR    | END_HOUR  |
| ------------- | ------------- | --------- |
| Morning Shift | 8:00          | 10:00     |
| Evening Shift | 13:00         | 17:00     |
| Night Shit    | 22:00         | 2:00      |
```

So I have to validate if an hour is between the start and end hours, I have a table with all hours as date that runs to this type of validation in a function

```
DECLARE @HOUR time = '9:00'
IF @HOUR BETWEEN @START_HOUR AND @END_HOUR
SELECT 'IS BETWEEN'
ELSE
SELECT 'IS NOT'
```

So it works fine on schedules where start hour and end hour are one after the other (the first two cases), but on the third case, an overnight schedule, it fails as it considers the end hour lower than the hour, like this case

```
DECLARE @HOUR time = '1:00'
-- Here START_HOUR is '22:00' AND END_HOUR is '2:00'
IF @HOUR BETWEEN @START_HOUR AND @END_HOUR
SELECT 'IS BETWEEN'
ELSE
SELECT 'IS NOT'
```

So it returns *IS NOT* but it should be considered that it is between that schedule

Just in case, no schedules end and start hour can be the same, and I'm using SQL Server 2014

Comment: Are times stored as datetime? 
If so, you could try retrieving data as datetime then add +1 day to end_hour in case start_hour is greater than end_hour.

Comment: @insilenzio they are stored as time, not datetime, and DATEADD function didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a design problem them. As @insilenzio said on his comment you should be saving the data as **DateTime**, not **Time**.

However you could cast the data to datetime before doing the comparison, setting the end_date greatter than star_date, and ensuring the hour to check is on the same day that end_date.
For example, taking your last example:

```
Change hour to : '2016-01-02 09:00:00'
Change star_hour to: '2016-01-01 22:00:00'
Change end_hour to: '2016-01-02 02:00:00'
```

Then your code will work with no problems. As I said, you mus ensure that @HOUR is on the same day that @END_HOUR. If not it will not operate correctly for obviously reasons.

As an example code you could use in SQL Server 2012 and greater: (maybe you will have to correct the sintax, but it's close to work)

```
DECLARE @HOUR Datetime = '2016-01-02 01:00:00'
IF @HOUR BETWEEN (cast('2016-01-01' as datetime) + cast(@START_HOUR as datetime)) AND (cast('2016-01-02' as datetime) + cast(@END_HOUR as datetime))
SELECT 'IS BETWEEN'
ELSE
SELECT 'IS NOT'
```

Answer (score 2):

If we stick to the `time` type, then one possible way is to check two intervals - up to midnight and from midnight.

```
DECLARE @HOUR time = '1:00';
DECLARE @START_HOUR time = '22:00';
DECLARE @END_HOUR time = '2:00';

IF @END_HOUR < @START_HOUR
BEGIN
    -- interval goes across the midnight
    IF @HOUR BETWEEN @START_HOUR AND '24:00'
        OR @HOUR BETWEEN '00:00' AND @END_HOUR
        SELECT 'IS BETWEEN'
    ELSE
        SELECT 'IS NOT'
    ;
END ELSE BEGIN
    -- interval is within the same day
    IF @HOUR BETWEEN @START_HOUR AND @END_HOUR
        SELECT 'IS BETWEEN'
    ELSE
        SELECT 'IS NOT'
    ;
END;
```

**Result**

```
(No column name)
IS BETWEEN
```

If we can use `datetime`, then I'd simply add 24 hours to `@END_HOUR`.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to convert time in minutes and make some calculationf in midnight cases:

```
DECLARE @HOUR time = '21:00'
DECLARE @START_HOUR time = '22:00'
DECLARE @END_HOUR time = '02:00'

DECLARE @START_MINUTES int = DATEPART(HOUR,@START_HOUR)*60 + DATEPART(MINUTE,@START_HOUR)
DECLARE @END_MINUTES int = DATEPART(HOUR,@END_HOUR)*60 + DATEPART(MINUTE,@END_HOUR)
DECLARE @MINUTES int = DATEPART(HOUR,@HOUR)*60 + DATEPART(MINUTE,@HOUR)

IF (@MINUTES < @START_MINUTES)
BEGIN
    SET @MINUTES = @MINUTES + 24 * 60
END

IF (@START_MINUTES < @END_MINUTES AND @MINUTES BETWEEN @START_MINUTES AND @END_MINUTES) OR (@START_MINUTES >= @END_MINUTES AND @MINUTES BETWEEN @START_MINUTES AND (@END_MINUTES + 24 * 60))
SELECT 'IS BETWEEN'
ELSE
SELECT 'IS NOT'
```